# How can I persist data with Symfony2's session service during a functional test?

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony

I'm writing a functional test for an action that uses Symfony2's session service to fetch data. In my test class's `setUp` method, I call `$this->get('session')->set('foo', 'bar');`. If I output all the session data (using `print_r($this->get('session')->all());`) either in `setUp` or in the actual test method, I get back `foo => bar`. But if I try outputting the session data from the action being tested, I get back an empty array. Does anyone know why this is happening, and how I can prevent it?

I should note that if I call `$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar'` from within `setUp()` the data is persisted and I can access it from the action - this problem seems local to Symfony2's session service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly try using your client's container (I'm assuming you're using WebTestCase):

```
$client = static::createClient();
$container = $client->getContainer();
```

If it still doesn't work try saving the session:

```
$session = $container->get('session');
$session->set('foo', 'bar');
$session->save();
```

I didn't try it in functional tests but that's how it works in Behat steps.

Comment: This works, but the downside is that I have to do this within each test method. I'm going to look for a way to do it in a more global scope, like the `setUp` method. Or I might try Behat :) Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the "session" service. 
With this service, you can :

- start the session,
- set some parameters into session,
- save the session,
- pass the Cookie with sessionId to the request

The code can be the following :

```
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Cookie;
....
....
public function testARequestWithSession()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $session = $client->getContainer()->get('session');
    $session->start(); // optional because the ->set() method do the start
    $session->set('foo', 'bar'); // the session is started  here if you do not use the ->start() method
    $session->save(); // important if you want to persist the params
    $client->getCookieJar()->set(new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId()));  // important if you want that the request retrieve the session

    $client->request( .... ...
```

The Cookie with $session->getId() has to be created after the start of the session

See Documentation  http://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/http_authentication.html#creating-the-authentication-token