# Symfony 2 - Adding session data to request object during unit testing

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to set up some testing for my REST API and I need to set a session variable inside the request object. The usual methods do not seem to work.

```
$session = $request->getSession();              
$session->set('my_session_variable', 'myvar');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [WebTestCase](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.0/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Tests/Functional/WebTestCase.php)

Then you can do things which are described in answer for similar question: [how-can-i-persist-data-with-symfony2s-session-service-during-a-functional-test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621359/how-can-i-persist-data-with-symfony2s-session-service-during-a-functional-test)

so something like:

```
$client = static::createClient();
$container = $client->getContainer();
$session = $container->get('session');
$session->set('name', 'Sensorario');
$session->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've tried that and read that article but I still get this: `Fatal error: Call to a member function getContainer() on a non-object`

Comment: Do your test class extends this one https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/WebTestCase.php ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use WebTestCase, you can retrieve the "session" service. 
With this service, you can :

- start the session,
- set some parameters into session,
- save the session,
- pass the Cookie with sessionId to the request

The code can be the following :

```
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Cookie;
....
....
public function testARequestWithSession()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $session = $client->getContainer()->get('session');
    $session->start(); // optional because the ->set() method do the start
    $session->set('my_session_variable', 'myvar'); // the session is started  here if you do not use the ->start() method
    $session->save(); // important if you want to persist the params
    $client->getCookieJar()->set(new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId()));  // important if you want that the request retrieve the session

    $client->request( .... ...
```

Answer (score -1):

A short snippet to set some value in session

```
$session = $this->client->getRequest()->getSession();
$session->set('name', 'Sensorario');
```

And a very very simple example to get this value

```
echo $session->get('name');
```

Comment: doesn't work... I have to manually create the request variable as it's coming from CLI

Comment: There is no $this->getRequest() in tests. And $this->$client->getRequest() in null before you did any request. So, it will not work